# Node / npm version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm not very confortable with node / npm (because I'm more a Backend Dev).
Now I use "nvm" to handle node / npm version (it seems to be a very good tool)
I have a React project that has been upgraded (Git Lab) to node 14.16.0 by our Infra Team.
So we have to align our configuration with this.

- Node 14 is set to work with npm 6.14.18.
- On our computer, Unbuntu set a npm 8.5.1
- Last npm version is 9.6.5 (I had lot of warning issue when running with)

So, which version of npm do I have to use with Node 14.16.0 (may I will set the 14.21.3 LTS) ?

Comment: Warnings are just that .. Warnings.  It's meant for you to read carefully through them and mitigate issues that you see as potential problems, and ignore the warnings that you **know** are just a warning, but you'll be OK.  If your app compiles (`npm run build`), I'd say most of your warnings pertain to known issues, that might not apply to your particular setup.

Comment: Check out the npm versions here `https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases`. I'd use the one `npm` that comes with the installed `node`.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, this shouldn't matter. If you are using a newer version of NPM locally than what CI is using, that's fine, since NPM is designed to be backwards compatible.

It may cause the lock file to change, but older versions of npm are even *forwards* compatible with newer lockfiles.

However you *do* need to be careful not to use NPM features available on your newer local version that aren't compatible with the older version in CI. But this is pretty easy to avoid because CI will just fail in the case that you do this and then you can react.

That said, it isn't *completely* unknown for bugs in a certain version to cause differing behaviour to what you are seeing locally because you are on a different version. It's not by design though -- NPM is largely backwards compatible -- those are rare bugs.

I wouldn't worry about the warning on NPM 9. Those aren't because of version mismatch issues, they just made NPM more shouty about certain things. The things it points out are also issues on other versions of NPM, it's just that the older ones never mentioned it. This is seen as an improvement as now it's letting you know of (minor) problems previous NPM versions didn't even mention.

If you really do care though about having the exact version you do in CI (I usually wouldn't care unless you were debugging a suspected difference between CI and local cause by the package manager -- a rare thing) then you can just:

```
nvm install 14
nvm use 14
npm install --global npm@6.14.18
```

Now your local NPM will match CI. But as above, personally, I wouldn't care about doing this unless I was debugging a specific rare issue suspected to be related to a version mismatch of the package manager.

> (may I will set the 14.21.3 LTS) ?

In my opinion yes. Above I just say `install 14` which will get the latest 14. Again, there could be cases where you notice different behaviour on the older 14 version when running in CI. But it's rare and I wouldn't fret over it unless an actual problem was encountered.

Ideally, of course, your devops team would use the latest version of the LTS on CI. Not doing so could be a security risk. See https://www.cybersecurity-help.cz/vdb/node_js_foundation/nodejs/14.16.0/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I has to use, for the moment en npm 8.xx because packageLock.json has is lock version 2.
I managed to set and run my React (16) project wiith Node 14.21.3 (LTS) and npm 8.19.4.

Now I am on a stable situation I'm going to try to update further.